# terraform retrieve file from URL

Tags: terraform

Here my concrete problem but the question is more generic: I'm creating a VM through a Terraform file with a certain cloud-init template.

```
resource "openstack_compute_instance_v2" "VM" {
....
 
  user_data = file('cloud-init')

}
```

Now , I'd like to re-use a cloud-init file that is external to the repository, let's say at `https://site/cloud-init`

```
  user_data = fromUrl('https://server/cloud-init')  #something like this
```

Is there a generic simple way to retrieve a file from an URL and uses it's contents?
Googling got me nowhere and I feel like the problem is generic enough.

I'd want to avoid having to 'curl it' myself.

**Update**: I don't necessarily mean an HTTP URL, could be a git, ssh ... URL.

Comment: What type of file is it, zip, JSON, text?

Comment: Use the http data source? https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/http/latest/docs/data-sources/http

Comment: @MarkoE , in this case .yaml text, but the question was in general wherever an external resource could be retrieved and used easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two approaches based on the type of content:

1. Use the [`http` data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/http/latest/docs/data-sources/http)
2. Use [`terraform_data` resource](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/resources/terraform-data)

For the `http` data source, two things are important:

> At present this resource can only retrieve data from URLs that respond with `text/*` or `application/json` content types, and expects the result to be UTF-8 encoded regardless of the returned content type header.

The second one is related to the security:

> Although `https` URLs can be used, there is currently no mechanism to authenticate the remote server except for general verification of the server certificate's chain of trust. Data retrieved from servers not under your control should be treated as untrustworthy.

If that is acceptable, then you can use the `http` data source, something like:

```
data "http" "cloud_init" {
  url = "https://server/cloud-init"

  # Optional request headers
  request_headers = {
    Accept = "text/yaml"
  }
}
```

Then, since this will be a YML file, you would have to decode it using [`yamldecode` built-in function](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/yamldecode):

```
resource "openstack_compute_instance_v2" "VM" {
....
 
  user_data = yamldecode(data.http.cloud_init.response_body)

}
```

The second approach is basically allowing you to run a shell command/script (which you would otherwise run manually) and download the file:

```
resource "terraform_data" "cloud_init" {
  triggers_replace = [] # you could tie downloading a file to some kind of a change in other resources 

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "curl -s -o ${path.root}/cloud-init.yaml https://server/cloud-init"
  }
}

resource "openstack_compute_instance_v2" "VM" {
....
 
  user_data = file("${path.root}/cloud-init.yaml")


  depends_on = [terraform_data.cloud_init]
}
```

As a side note, the second approach creates an explicit dependency between resources with `depends_on`, so the first approach is probably a bit more elegant.

Answer (score 2):

To get the file from a URL, you may use the `http` resource:

```
data "http" "my_file" {
  url = var.my_file_url

  request_headers = {
    "Authorization" = "Bearer TOKEN" # (if you need it)
  }
}
```

Then, you can do whatever you want with the data you get. For example, if your data is a JSON that you need to use as a Terraform object:

```
locals {
  jsondecode(data.http.my_file.response_body)
}
```